# Disabling input when checkbox in checked inside a repeater

Tags: jquery

I have this running when my page loads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".indent1").each(function(){
        if($(":checkbox").is(':checked')){
            $('input[type="text"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
});});
```

The code is incorrectly disabling the text boxes in the 2nd repeater
even though the check box is not locked.
How can I correctly disable only the first text box?
[html page with text incorrectly disabled in 2nd repeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS8Kb.jpg)
Robyn

Comment: We need to see the HTML. A question should always have a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your function disables *every* `input[type=text]`, not just the one inside your repeater. Assuming that the input you're trying to disable is a child of `.indent1`, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".indent1").each(function(){
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    var $input = $(this).find('input[type="text"]');
    if($checkbox.is(':checked')){
      $input.prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```